# import.php: Missing parameter: import_type error in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

For the last several hours I've been searching and attempting to fix this. It's killing me that I can't figure it out.

Running any SQL gives me this error:

```
import.php: Missing parameter: import_type
import.php: Missing parameter: format
```

Similar messages appear for export.

I also can't access Page Number 2 of the database or do any sorting in the structure tab.

I found this

> http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_2.8

and have checked for everything on this list. In fact, `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']` doesn't appear in any `config.inc.php` file I looked at.

I am running CentOS 5 & WHM/cPanel.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply a hard refresh of the page (`CTRL + R` or `CMD + R`) or else logging out and in again made the issue disappear for me. It seems to have something to do with the session.

Comment: Yup. Tried new session in incognito mode and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, you need to change a session file in the phpmyadmin directory:

```
cd / opt / psa / admin / htdocs / domains / databases / phpMyAdmin / libraries / 
mv session.inc.php session.inc.php-old 

wget http://download1.swsoft.com/Plesk/Autoupdate/Windows/8.1.1.2/120220/session.inc.php
/ Etc / init.d / psa restart
```

Comment: just check for cent files for same.

Comment: @MichaelT Do you have root access? Do you have shell command access ?

Comment: What is the size of sql you are trying to upload