# how to merge two mysql tables with same structure

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have 2 tables with same structure and same id (as primary key) but different data :

[image: two mysql tables with same structure but different data]

Now, I need to merge them and have something like this :

[image: merged mysql table]

It is important to not change id of rows and not insert new records.

How can I do that using a MySQL query ?

Comment: Are the ids from two table related?

Comment: Yes, just like the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you just need to performe an `UPDATE` query with an `INNER JOIN` of the two table. I assume `id` columns are realted so

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.fax = b.fax
```

Otherwise you can set a new table and take values by join two previous table as follow

```
INSERT INTO table3 (id, tel, fax) 
SELECT a.id, a.tel, b.fax
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fabio, but while I am trying to run this query in PHPMyAdmin, I get this error : import.php: Missing parameter: 
import.php: Missing parameter:

Comment: This seems an error related to phpmyadmin missing a file

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929583/import-php-missing-parameter-import-type-error-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Wow! Worked! Thank you very very much Fabio! It was Great!

Answer (score 1):

First, backup your data. Then, if you only want to end up with one table (and the primary keys match), then try this:

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `table1`.`fax` = `table2`.`fax`
WHERE `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`;
```

If that doesn't work, it's a good thing you made a backup.

)